How do I stop metro / RN from spewing system logs into the console?
After moving our Expo React Native app into a turbo repo, I'm seeing a bunch of console logs I didn't see before, here's an example:
[PlugInKit] <PKDaemonClient: 0x600000421380>: XPC error talking to pkd: Connection interrupted
[AudioToolbox] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:2773 iOSSimulatorAudioDevice-17759-2: Abandoning I/O
cycle because reconfig pending (2).
[CoreAudio] HALSystem.cpp:2216 AudioObjectPropertiesChanged: no such object
[AudioToolbox] AQMEIO_HAL.cpp:2552 timeout
[CoreAudio] AudioHardware-mac-imp.cpp:2706 AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID

This is undesirable and cluttering, but I can't find any settings for this on my searches.
Anyone familiar?
